# Loopbackjs: Cannot cancel a hook (ie: beforeSave)

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Actually I'm trying to cancel a hook to avoid duplicate pair entity-name/subname - by a server-side check.

My example is, if an entity already exists with the same name and subname, I'd like it not to be created/persisted.

Here's my code so far in my *entity.js*:

```
module.exports = function (ContactType) {
    ContactType.observe('before save', function filterSameEntities(ctx, next) {
        if (ctx.instance) {
            ContactType.find({where: {name: ctx.instance.name, subname: crx.instance.subname}}, function (err, ct) {
                if (ct.length > 0) {
                    //I'd like to exit and not create/persist the entity.
                    next(new Error("There's already an entity with this name and subname"));
                }
            });
        }
        next();
    });
};
```

Actually the error is correctly displayed, **but** the entity is still created and I would like that it wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Would it be easier to create unique index in your model definition file or to use validators https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Validating+model+data ?

Comment: Haha, you're right for that case, but my real problem was too check on the uniqueness of a pair (name + subname)... I'll update my question...

Comment: In that case you can have composite index on your model. Thomas gave you a good answer on how to prevent save action, but my point is that you can get rid of unnecessary code. You can have composite index defined like this   "indexes": {
    "name_subname_index": {
      "keys": {
        "name": 1,
        "subname": 1
      },
      "options": {
        "unique": true
      }
    }
  } This will prevent duplicate values without additional code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your last `next();` statement is always called, hence the save-action always happens.

You can end further execution using `return`.
Keep in mind that `.find()` is async, so just adding `return` inside the callback would still cause that last `next();` statement to run.

Please try this:

```
module.exports = function (ContactType) {
    ContactType.observe('before save', function filterSameEntities(ctx, next) {
        if (!ctx.instance) {
            return next();
        }

        ContactType.find({where: {name: ctx.instance.name, subname: ctx.instance.subname}}, function (err, ct) {
            if (err) {    // something went wrong with our find
                return next(err);
            }

            if (ct.length > 0) {
                //I'd like to exit and not create/persist the entity.
                return next(new Error("There's already an entity with this name and subname"));
            }

            return next();
        });
    });
};
```